# one-to-many double mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I want to map 2 entities using one-to-many relationship.

The two entities are airport and flight_schedule.

one airport can have many flight schedules.

But, one flight schedule can have 2 airports. departure airport, and arrived airport are them.

So, I want to make them one-to-many association twice.

I mean, airport and flight_schedule have the twice same relationship.

I hope you can understand this situation.

So, what I did is :

Airport.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Airport implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer airportId;
private String name;
private String country;
private String city;
private Set<String> gateway = new HashSet<String>(0);
private Set<FlightSchedule> depFlightSchedule = new HashSet<FlightSchedule>(0);
private Set<FlightSchedule> arrFlightSchedule = new HashSet<FlightSchedule>(0);

public Airport() {
}

public Airport(String name, String country, String city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.country = country;
    this.city = city;
}

public Airport(String name, String country, String city, Set<String> gateway, Set<FlightSchedule> depFlightSchedule, Set<FlightSchedule> arrFlightSchedule) {
    this.name = name;
    this.country = country;
    this.city = city;
    this.gateway = gateway;
    this.depFlightSchedule = depFlightSchedule;
    this.arrFlightSchedule = arrFlightSchedule;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "airport_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getAirportId() {
    return this.airportId;
}

.... getters and setters .... 

@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "gateway", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "airport_id"))
@Column(name = "gateway_no") 
public Set<String> getGateway() {
    return this.gateway;
}

public void SetGateway(Set<String> gateway) {
    this.gateway = gateway;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "depAirport")
public Set<FlightSchedule> getDepFlightSchedule() {
    return this.depFlightSchedule;
}

public void setDepFlightSchedule(Set<FlightSchedule> depFlightSchedule) {
    this.depFlightSchedule = depFlightSchedule;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "arrAirport")
public Set<FlightSchedule> getArrFlightSchedule() {
    return this.arrFlightSchedule;
}

public void setArrFlightSchedule(Set<FlightSchedule> arrFlightSchedule) {
    this.arrFlightSchedule = arrFlightSchedule;
}

}
```

The last two '@OneToMany' is the very relationship between airport and flight_schedule.

Also, below is FlightSchedule.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class FlightSchedule implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer flightscheduleId;
private Date depDay;
private Date depTime;
private Date arrDay;
private Date arrTime;
private Double flightTime;
private Set<BoardingPass> boardingPasses = new HashSet<BoardingPass>(0);
private Airplane airplane;
private Airport depAirport;
private Airport arrAirport;

public FlightSchedule() {
}

public FlightSchedule(Date depDay, Date depTime, Date arrDay, Date arrTime) {
    this.depDay = depDay;
    this.depTime = depTime;
    this.arrDay = arrDay;
    this.arrTime = arrTime;
}

public FlightSchedule(Date depDay, Date depTime, Date arrDay, Date arrTime, Double flightTime) {
    this.depDay = depDay;
    this.depTime = depTime;
    this.arrDay = arrDay;
    this.arrTime = arrTime;
    this.flightTime = flightTime;
}

public FlightSchedule(Date depDay, Date depTime, Date arrDay, Date arrTime, Double flightTime, 
        Set<BoardingPass> boardingPasses, Airplane airplane, Airport depAirport, Airport arrAirport) {
    this.depDay = depDay;
    this.depTime = depTime;
    this.arrDay = arrDay;
    this.arrTime = arrTime;
    this.flightTime = flightTime;
    this.boardingPasses = boardingPasses;
    this.airplane = airplane;
    this.depAirport = depAirport;
    this.arrAirport = arrAirport;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getFlightscheduleId() {
    return this.flightscheduleId;
}

public void setFlightscheduleId(Integer flightscheduleId) {
    this.flightscheduleId = flightscheduleId;
}

....getters and setters... 

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "airport_id", nullable = false)
public Airport getDepAirport() {
    return this.depAirport;
}

public void setDepAirport (Airport depAirport) {
    this.depAirport = depAirport;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "airport_id", nullable = false)
public Airport getArrAirport() {
    return this.arrAirport;
}

public void setArrAirport (Airport arrAirport) {
    this.arrAirport = arrAirport;
}

}
```

As above, the last two '@ManyToOne' is the very relationship between airport and flight_schedule.

Through this code, I got an error which is 'MappingException'.

It says RootClass(PersistentClass).checkColumnDuplication(Set, Iterator).

How can I figure that relation? How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that a flight schedule has two different airports:

> But, one flight schedule can have 2 airports. departure airport, and arrived airport are them.

However, you are trying to map both `depAirport` and `arrAirport` to the same column `airport_id`. You should change it for whatever are the foreign key columns in the table, like `@JoinColumn(name="dep_airport_id")` and `@JoinColumn(name="arr_airport_id")`, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Because the name of id in airport table is 'airport_id'. I thought ``@JoinColumn(name="database schema name")`` isn't it? How could it be changed?

Comment: You are not supposed to tell what is the primary key of Airport in there but the column that has the foreign key in the table of `FlightSchedule`.

For instance, `@JoinColumn(name="dep_airport_id")` and `@JoinColumn(name="arr_airport_id")`, respectively.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean, I can use Foreign Key at ``@JoinColumn(name=" ")``. Still, my hibernate doesn't work, but the problem was solved!! Thanks!